# Default screenshot loads when I run app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, ios-simulator, screenshot

When I build and run my app, Default.png shows up first for about 2 seconds, and then switches to the app. This happens in both the simulator and on the device. I tried deleting Default.png then cleaned all targets, but this still happened. Has this happened to anyone before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear your simulator cache... anyways, restore simulator.